# I cannot output print quotation text and out at the same time

Tags: python

For my school project I am working on a playlist generator, and I am stuck, see this code here?

```
elif SuggestionMetal == "n":
        SongsMetal = input("Please can you input what songs you want in your playlist: ")
    print ("You have chosen" (SongsMetal))
```

The portion where is says "print ("You have chosen" (SongsMetal))", isnt working, and I don't know why. Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\ComputingProjectUpdated.py", line 21, in 
>       print ("You have choosen" (SongsMetal)) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Can someone please help me? Thanks. I am working in Python 3.6.2 btw.

Comment: print ("You have chosen" ,SongsMetal). Read [here](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~takebaya/cent110/simple_io/simple_io.html)

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Please use `.format()` or f-string while using `Python>=3.6`.

```py
print('You have chosen {}'.format(SongsMetal)) # the {} is a place holder, used to add any variable.
```

> Also note that python variables should be small-cased and separated by underscore; for example: `songs_metal` instead of `SongsMetal`. The latter is often used in Java. See the [python variable naming conventions](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-conventions).

[image: python-variable-naming-convention]

### References

1. [python-variable-naming-convention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/705Dd.png)
2. [Look for heading: **#2 “New Style” String Formatting (str.format)**](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)

Answer (score 0):

> The portion where is says "print ("You have chosen" (SongsMetal))", isnt working, and I don't know why.

It's because you are trying to call a string, as your error states. What does that mean? If you want to call something in python (for example a function) you could say:

```
my_function(my_input)
```

In which python would "call" my_function, and take my_input as input.
In your case, instead of calling a function, you are calling the string "You have chosen". The reason it's attempting to call the string is because you have () after the string where you are trying to append SongsMetal, it's reading SongsMetal as your input to your function (string), "You have chosen". So in this case, my_function is your string, "You have chosen", and my_input is your input SongsMetal, which is interpreted as

```
"You have chosen"(SongsMetal)
```

If you take out the unnecessary (), you would actually get a different error (syntax).

```
SongsMetal = input("Please can you input what songs you want in your playlist: ")
print ("You have chosen" SongsMetal)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So you could fix the error by simply appending your string with a +

```
print ("You have chosen" + " " + SongsMetal)
```

or by simply printing 2 items:

```
print ("You have chosen" , SongsMetal)
```

You could also write a function then call it inside the print statement, like this:

```
def my_function():
    SongsMetal = input("Please can you input what songs you want in your playlist: ")
    mytext = "You have chosen"
    return " ".join([mytext, SongsMetal])

print (my_function())
```

This last function is what python is trying to interpret your code as, since you added () after a string, it is attempting to read the string as a function/class, such as "somestring"(), which will result in your error.

Answer (score -1):

```
print ("You have chosen", (SongsMetal))
```

That will be good.

Comment: You don't need the inner parentheses:
print("You have chosen", SongsMetal)

Comment: It is. In *some* places it does not actively hurt (other than in understanding) but in other situations there *must*, or there must *not* be parentheses. Best to learn the right way instead of a rote of "keep adding parentheses until the error goes away".